# tableview header and prototype cell showing wrong

Tags: swift, tableview

Is there are reason why there are height differences between what is shown and what has been set as a height? also there is a space between header and prototype cell which I cannot get rid of.

```
extension FirstTabThirdView: UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView (_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = headerView
        return view
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellOne", for: indexPath)
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = "hello"
        return cell
    }  
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please share the code for headerView.

Comment: there is no code for headerView. I made that with Storyboard. But it looks like I solved all my problems except the space between header and prototype cell. The other problems I solved by clicking on table view and then setting the height and not on the header itself.

Comment: In that case you should remove the function viewForHeaderInSection. Also please read this: https://programmingwithswift.com/how-to-add-header-footer-view-in-uitableview-in-storyboard/